# iptables how to block clients each other

Tags: iptables

I've a guest network (192.168.2.0/24) connected by routing to my linux box (192.168.1.0/24).
I'd like, permits clients go online (I already done this), but I need a rule to blocks clients to see each other (on the same subnet 192.168.2.0/24).

My goal is that all clients can't communicate to other clients in that lan (192.168.2.0/24).

Comment: Presumably you're going to apply this rule to all guest clients? Therefore, I take it you're limiting all clients to Linux if you're requesting information on doing this with `iptables`?

Comment: You can't do this at the IP layer on the router 'cos clients won't talk to the router for that.  If you're only providing WiFi guestnet access then you might be able to do it via _wireless isolation_; see http://www.howtogeek.com/179089/lock-down-your-wi-fi-network-with-your-routers-wireless-isolation-option/ for details.

Comment: I wrote about AP isolation. Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to limit this with iptables on your Linux Box this is not possible, because if the clients are in the same subnet they communicate with each other directly without passing through the default gateway/your Linux Box